# How to force kubernetes gitlab-runner to use the host network?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I need to have my containers connect to the gitlab-runners host network in order to run ansible against other servers in my pipeline. I am using a kubernetes runner.

Is there a way to force the runner to use pods on the host network?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer without changing anything in the kubernetes cluster was to add the host network into the containers `/etc/hosts` file with the following commands in my gitlab job:

```
 script:
    # use host network
    - echo "127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4" >> /etc/hosts
    - echo "::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6" >> /etc/hosts
```